# How do I enable my mouse when also typing on a Lenovo with Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, mouse

I recently bought a new laptop. It is a Lenovo with Windows 8.1 and whenever I play games like mine craft it doesn't let me walk with W and look or move around at the same time. I have watched many tutorials online on how to fix this but none seem to work or are all for Windows 8. Whenever I go to my mouse settings the last tab says 'ELAN' but when I watch YouTube videos and tutorials it says different.

Please help! :)

Comment: By mouse you mean the track-pad or an actual mouse? Mention your laptop's model number also.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows 10:

You should try going to Settings → Devices → Mouse and touchpad. You will find a section called "Touchpad" and directly under it you will see a drop-down menu that specifies an amount of delay. You should turn it to "No delay (always on)."

For Windows 8.1:

Try going to Control Panel → Hardware and Sound → Mouse → Device Settings → Press the button "Settings..." While I do not have the same laptop as you, and thus I cannot give you a definitive answer, there might be a setting in that panel that will allow you to change when the touchpad is on.

Comment: Ok I just tried it and it didn't work so I restarted and before I logged into my laptop it was working but once I was logged in and on my desktop I tried it again and it wasn't working.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I thought you were running Windows 10. I updated my answer.

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you told me what specific laptop you have.

Comment: I have a Lenovo with Windows 8.1

Comment: Lenovo has over 24 different laptop product lines, each having additional variations. You can see examples of their different series [on this page.](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/)

Comment: I'm not sure because when I bought it, it didn't say and I don't know how to check. I didn't get it from the official site.

Comment: Its a G50-80, I found a sticker on my laptop